# How to pass s-exp to parameter of non s-exp type in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

Question: How to force a s-exp to be evaluated before passing to a function expecting parameter of string type or else.?

This code is fine (no error):

```
(setf (slot-value (ole sheet :range "A1:B1") 'value)
   `(("123" "456"))))
```

However, when passing a s-exp such as (first line) instead of "123":

```
(setf line '("123" "456"))

(setf (slot-value (ole sheet :range "A1:B1") 'value)
   `(((first line) (second line)))))
```

There is error message:

> The value FIRST is not of the expected type (OR
>                                               STRING
>                                               FIXNUM
>                                               SINGLE-FLOAT
>                                               DOUBLE-FLOAT).
>     [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
>
> Restarts:
>   0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
>   1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
>   2: [ABORT-BREAK] Reset this thread
>   3: [ABORT] Kill this thread

I know what the problem is. But is there way get rid of this restriction? Because we would need to put the line of code inside a loop, so can't fix the parameter value to such as "123"...

I try using macro:

```
(defmacro set-line (par1 par2)
  `(setf (slot-value (ole sheet :range "A1:B1") 'value)
     `((,par1 ,par2))))
```

However, it doesn't work. Still the same error message saying the wrong type (first line)...

```
(set-line (first line) (second line))
```

Also I don't know how to escape the backquote ` if it appears inside macro body. I have tried put a \ in front of backquote inside the macro body, but then the \ would also appear upon macro expand.

```
`(setf xxx  `  <--- another backquote 
`(setf xxx  \`  <--- this can't escape backquote inside macro body
```

Thanks.

Background: when playing with Win32 OLE Excel example in: 
https://github.com/quek/cl-win32ole/blob/master/example/excel.lisp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the basics of quotation. Your expression

```
? `(("123" "456")) ; quasiquote
(("123" "456"))
```

is a list containing a list and can also be created using the function `LIST` as

```
? (list (list "123" "456")) ; list
(("123" "456"))
```

To use expressions, you can either use unquote (note the preceding comma)

```
? `((,(first line) ,(second line))) ; quasiquote with unquote
(("123" "456"))
```

or, better

```
? `(,line)
(("123" "456"))
```

or use `list` :

```
? (list line)
(("123" "456"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I should have just put comma in the front. Before that I also think about putting comma, but I only put it into an (incorrect) macro, so further get confused by myself...Now I also read http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm, the backquote parameter is eql. to   (append (list (list (first s) (second s))) '() ). When I see your answer later, I see cleaner syntax. Thanks again.